# New Leads Assigned to Sales Users in Order basis

Tags: leads, assignment-rules

I would like to arrange new leads assigned to Sales Users in order basis. Is there a way by using the Lead Assignment Rule

like new Lead ---> sales 1
 another new lead ---> sales2
 another new lead ---> sales3
 another new lead ---> sales4
 another new lead ---> sales5

Then it goes in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How do I create a round-robin assignment for Leads or Cases to users?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004000) in Help & Training. basically, you create an auto-number field, then a formula that divides the auto-number field by some value, then an assignment rule that uses the results of that formula to determine which user to assign to.

I've copied the current text for posterity:

> To assign leads (or cases) that are either manually created or created
> using Web to Lead (or Case). Follow the instructions below:
>
> The first steps for lead or case assignment is to create two custom
> fields that can be included in the page layouts for users or hidden as
> they are strictly for the assignment mechanism based on the custom
> formula. The instructions below assume the setup is for leads.
>
> 1. Create an auto number field in leads called "Lead Number" that spans 0 decimal places and had the format "{0}" (exclude the inverted
>    commas). Below are the steps to create Auto number field:
>
> a) Click on Setup | Customize | Lead | Field.
>
> b) Scroll down and click
> on “New” button on “Lead Custom Fields & Relationships”.
>
> c) Scroll
> down and select “Auto Number” radio button.Enter “Field Label” (eg –
> Lead Number) with that spans 0 decimal places and had the format "{0}"
> (exclude the inverted commas).
>
> d) Click on Next for “Field-Level
> Security for Profile”Click on “Save” to include it different Page
> Layout Name.
>
> 2. Create a custom formula field with return type number in leads called "Round_Robin_ID" and use the formula: MOD(VALUE(Lead_Number__c)
>    ,3) +1
> 3. Use the value of this formula field in your lead assignment rules to assign lead records to different queues or users: Round_Robin_ID =
>    1 is assigned to Queue A (User 1) Round_Robin_ID = 2 is assigned to
>    Queue B (User 2) Round_Robin_ID = 3 is assigned to Queue C (User 3)
>
> Explanation of the process: The following formula example for leads
> assumes you have 3 lead queues and you want to assign an equal number
> of incoming leads to each queue. You can also assign cases using a
> similar formula.
>
> MOD(VALUE(Lead_Number__c) ,3) +1 is the formula for a custom formula
> field named Round_Robin_ID that assigns each lead a value of 1, 2, or
> 3. This formula uses a custom auto-number field called Lead Number that assigns each lead a sequential number starting with 1. The MOD
> function divides the lead number by the number of lead queues
> available (3 in this example) and returns a remainder of 1, 2, or 3.
>
> Remember:  It will not work on the existing records. In order to make
> the rule trigger for existing records you should "Mass" update the
> records. If you are creating a record manually, you can check the
> "Assign using active assignment rule" under options so that the record
> follows the assignment rule at the time of creation.

Comment: Could I create a Lead number with format {00000} or it has to be {0} ?

Comment: @DominicSeb You may use anywhere from 1 to 10 zeros. However, VALUE does not accept non-numeric strings, so do not add any dashes, letters, etc.